# User and Link association difficulties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, schema

I have a user and link MVC. I listed them below. Essentially when I create a new link I want it to be tied to my user and then display the users email with the quote on my show page, but I continue to get a nil value for a user when I authenticate even though I have:

1. a user and link assocation
2. permitted `:user_id` in my strong parameters
3. have a before_filter that requires a user be logged in when making a new request
4. have a user_id in my link schema

If you take a look at my show.html.erb and the line `<%= @link.user.try(:email) %>`, this is where the users email should appear that posted the link, but they all come across as nil values.

I am a little lost right now as to why I can't get this to work, any help would be very appreciated!

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
  acts_as_voter
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_votable
  attr_accessor :avatar
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

Controllers:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @links = Link.all
  end

  def show
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @link = Link.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)

    if @link.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def link_params
    params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url, :avatar, :user_id)
  end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Author:</strong>
  <%= @link.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Quote:</strong>
  <%= @link.url %>
</p>

<small class="author">Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@link.created_at) %> ago by <%= @link.user.try(:email) %></small>
```

Schema:

```
create_table "links", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "cached_votes_total", default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_score", default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_up",    default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_down",  default: 0
    t.string   "avatar"
  end

 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like user_id is ever set. As it happens, you probably don't want to set it via the params anyway (since these can be manipulated by the user).

Instead, replace

```
 @link = Link.new(link_params)
```

With

```
 @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)
```

If links always have a user, I would also mark the `user_id` column as not null instead of littering my app with calls to `try` (And I would in general prefer `try!` to `try`)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, the association is now working properly. Out of my own curiosity, why do you think the link_params were not setting the user? In regards to your last remarks, I should run a migration changing user_id to be null: false in my links table?

Comment: Because your form most likely didn't have a user_id field (or it was blank). I would write a migration to change nullness of user_id but that is up to you (and you would need to remove any rows with null user_id)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

1.As I understand, the logic is that you can only create links once your logged in. And a user can create links only for him/her (only user logged in can be the owner of links he created). In that case you should not expose user_id in form but instead add it in the create action:

```
 def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)

    if @link.save
      current_user.links << @link
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

2.Also, if you don't allow orphan links(with no user as the owner), then I suggest not using `user.try(:email)` but instead `@link.user.email`

3. If you are accessing user object through `@link` then you could preload it in the show action to save some DB queries

   ```
   def show   
    @link = Link.includes(:user).find(params[:id])  
   end
   ```

Make these changes and try again. Also, email is required for a user if you are using default devise configuration, so `.try(:email)` returning nil might mean that the `user` object is not found, which means that the associations are not properly set (my version might fix that)